# Strange display error with VBA charts - x-values as dates

Tags: excel, vba, date, format, x-axis

I'm running this script. The goal is to put two data series into the plot area, which works. Values are random.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LWAs_Erzeugen()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("B3 Graph")


With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Select

        ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select

        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""LWA_aus_B1"""
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='B2 PV Production'!$B$43:$BX$43"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).values = "='B2 PV Production'!$B$46:$BX$46"

        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Delete
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "=""LWA_aus_C0"""
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "='B2 PV Production'!$B$43:$BX$43"
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).values = "='C0 EV (Historie)'!$D$3:$BZ$3"

        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("E14").value
        ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("E15").value

End With


End Sub
```

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = Range("E14").value
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Range("E15").value
```

Yes, I can do a with-block - but it doesn't work for me, I don't know why. Do not focus on that, please.
The last two lines don't work as they should. What am I doing wrong? Instead of displaying an x-axis with dates as min/max values I get something else. The format is shown but no values!

[image]

Now the funky stuff: When I right-click and go to "select data" and click on any of the data series in the left list the dates appear! What is happening here?

[image]

Comment: Manipulating charts in VBA can run into strange Excel bugs; you code is probably fine (why do you think that the last two lines are the problem?) You could try adding `ActiveChart.Refresh` at the end. Failing that, please build a simplified version that we can all try out without recreating you whole workbook.

Comment: I think it might have to do something with the values being dates, since Excel always struggles with them. 
I already tried ActiveChart.Refresh, it has no effect.

Could you quickly tell me where I can add such a file in this post? I tried to edit but found no possibility to add a file

Comment: @2mas You need to add it to some public sharing site (eg DropBox, OneDrive) and then post a link in your question. Not everyone will download a workbook, especially one with macros. Better to add your data as text which can be copy/pasted using something like this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to format it properly.

Comment: Let me voice another issue beforehand: In my test file now I get error 1004 for this line... 'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).values = "='B2 PV Production'!$B$46:$BX$46"' Wtf has happened, I left the code the same.

I still uploaded it, I'll fix it tomorrow, if you don't mind. Maybe you see the eror before me, I don't know wtf it is doing. Could you give me an email so I can link you to onedrive?